# Ajuda Combo dinamico com javascript

Tags: php, javascript, oracle, combobox

Estou fazendo alguns testes com PHP + Oracle e estou com uma duvida. Fiz um combo, que pega dados do Oracle, e que controla um textfield. Só que agora preciso atualizar mais um textfield, mas não tem jeito. Alguem pode me ajudar?

OBS: Nesse text no codigo aparece normal a descrição, mas preciso adicionar o "setor" em outro.....

JavaScript

```
function alimentarCampo() {
        var codCampo = document.getElementById("codCampo");
        document.getElementById("descrCampo").value = codCampo.options[codCampo.selectedIndex].value;
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
  //Inicia seleção Combo e descreve no Text (Maquinas)
?>
             <tr>
                 <td>Máquina:</td>
                 <td><select id="codCampo" name="codMaquinas" onchange="alimentarCampo();">
                 <option></option>
             <?
                 include('config.php'); //conexao com o banco
                 //monta dados do combo das maquinas
                 $consulta = OCIParse($ora_conexao,"select CODIGO,NOME,SETOR from pcn_manut_maquina
                                                    order by CODIGO");
                 OCIDefineByName($consulta,"CODIGO",$v_num);
                 OCIDefineByName($consulta,"NOME",$v_nome);
                 OCIDefineByName($consulta,"SETOR",$v_setor);
                 OCIExecute($consulta);
                     while (OCIFetch($consulta)){
                        echo "<option value=\"".$v_nome."\">".$v_num."</option>";  //PRECISA DAS \ PARA PEGAR CAMPOS COM ESPAÇO
                     }
                        echo "</td>";

             ?>
            </tr>

              <tr>
                 <td></td>
                 <td><input type="text" id="descrCampo" name="descrMaquinas" readonly="true" size="60"></td>
              </tr>
```

Comment: Isso me cheira muito cara de Ajax..... acho que facilitaria sua vida

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma alternativa é no PHP colocar o nome + setor no VALUE:

```
echo "<option value=\"".$v_nome."|" . $v_setor . "\">".$v_num."</option>";
```

e no Javascript,

```
    function alimentarCampo() {
            var codCampo = var x = document.getElementById("codCampo").selectedIndex;
            var campos = codCampo.split("|");
            document.getElementById("descrCampo").value = campos[0];
            document.getElementById("setor").value = campos[1];
    }
```